# Update multiple items

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to update a few items in real time without having to change the page.

I already use something like this for another item which updates every 5 seconds.

I tried doing it for each item but it made my website VERY slow.

I was told it could be done with jQuery but I didnt know how exactly.

**What I want to do:**

Using PHP I will be getting information from my database which will either say "1" or "0"

This I need updated will be these: (if they are 1)

```
<a id="first_icon" style="background: url(/images/first.gif); height:23px; width:23px; float:left; margin-right:3px;" href="first.php" title="First"></a>
<a id="sec_icon" style="background: url(/images/first.gif); height:23px; width:23px; float:left; margin-right:3px;" href="sec.php" title="Second"></a>
<a id="third_icon" style="background: url(/images/first.gif); height:23px; width:23px; float:left; margin-right:3px;" href="third.php" title="Third"></a>
<a id="four_icon" style="background: url(/images/first.gif); height:23px; width:23px; float:left; margin-right:3px;" href="four.php" title="Fourth"></a>
```

If they are "0" the icon "id" will be something like "first_icon_2"

How can I get a request for all of them at once??

Thanks in advanced, I have tried to do this for about a month.

Comment: If you tried to do this for a month, you have to show us _"What have you tried?"_

Comment: It won't benefit anything because it didn't work and won't work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is an ajax call.  jQuery has an `.ajax()` function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ which is extremely straight forward.

Essentially, what you need to do is set up a PHP script which does any processing that you need done.  Anything that is echoed out onto the page will be returned via the `ajax` call.  If you're looking to process multiple items, you should look into `JSON`.

Since it seems like you need to return multiple values (1 for each of the icons) you will want to create an array in PHP.  The array will look something like this:

```
$icons = array("first_icon => 1, "second_icon => 0, "third_icon" => 0, "fourth_icon => 1);
```

You can then use `json_encode` to encode the array into a string which will be readable on your javascript side:

```
$iconsJSON = json_encode($icons);
echo $iconsJSON;
```

If you set up your AJAX function on your main page (the one with the javascript) like the following, you will be able to reference any of the `icon` keys.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'JSON',
type: 'POST',
url: api_url+'client/'+client.id+'.json', 
data: {
    variable1: 'value',
    variable2: 'value',
    variable3: 'value'
},
success: function(data) {
    // On success perform this function
    var icons = data;
},
error: function(data) {
    // On failure perform this function
}
});
```

I would recommend reading through this resource if you need more guidance: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/